# How do I add a "flag" to an issue via the JIRA rest API

Tags: rest, jira

So I've been doing some research into this and it seems that "Flagged" is a custom field in Jira (https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/flag-an-issue/). If an issue is flagged, customfield_12345 (in my case) of said issue will have a self, a value "Impediment", and an id. If an issue is not flagged its customfield_12345 will simply be None (I'm using python).

I can easily use "GET" to determine if an issue is flagged or not, but when I try to use "PUT"

```
 {"fields": {
     "customfield_12345": [
        {
           "value": "Impediment"
        }
      ]
    }
 }
```

with the url `https://<domain>/rest/api/2/issue/<issuekey>`, I get `"Field 'customfield_12345' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown"`.

I found some threads that suggest adding `?overrideScreenSecurity=true` to the URL, but that does not work (explained here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-set-overrideScreenSecurity-true-with-Python/qaq-p/1191932).

I don't seem to be able to simply add the field to the edit screen in Jira either since I'm not an administrator. The only way a user can flag an issue is by right clicking it in the backlog or "board view".

How do I update the value of the "Flagged" custom field in Jira via the rest API?

Comment: Hmm. You could try using the Inspect right hand button menu in Chrome to view the network calls made when you flag an issue in an agile board

Comment: Looks like it is a POST to rest/greenhopper/1.0/xboard/issue/flag/flag.json

Comment: Doesn't appear in the docs at https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/7.3.1/ though so it's not supported officially